# How can I use rxBleGattCallback.setNativeCallback(bluetoothGattCallback)?

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2, rxandroidble

I have a rxBleConnection and I'm trying set native BluetoothGattCallback to rxBleGattCallback but it doesn't work because my BluetoothGattCallback doesn't detect any event.
My code is the next, can somebody help me, please?

```
class MyRxBleCustomOperation: RxBleCustomOperation<Any> {

    override fun asObservable(bluetoothGatt: BluetoothGatt?, rxBleGattCallback: RxBleGattCallback?,
                              scheduler: Scheduler?): Observable<Any> {
        rxBleGattCallback?.setNativeCallback(bluetoothGattCallback)
        return Observable.just("")
    }

    private val bluetoothGattCallback = object : BluetoothGattCallback() {
        override fun onCharacteristicChanged(gatt: BluetoothGatt?, characteristic: BluetoothGattCharacteristic?) {
            super.onCharacteristicChanged(gatt, characteristic)
            Timber.e("SOME CHARACTERISTIC CHANGED") //Here It doesn't detect nothing
        }
    }
}
```

..............I call from some class................

```
rxBleConnection.queue(myRxBleCustomOperation()).subscribe()
```

I expect to detect all onCharacteristicChanged because I have to concatenate all data received

Answer (score 0):

From the Javadoc of `RxBleGattCallback.setNativeCallback()`:

> The callback reference will be automatically released after the operation is terminated.

You are returning `Observable.just("")` that completes (terminates) right after the subscription. That is why you do not get any callbacks as your callback is detached almost immediately.

If you need to concatenate all data received from all active notifications you can easily do it by merging them:

```
val allNotificationsObs: Observable<ByteArray> =
    Observable.merge( // still need to activate all wanted notifications
        rxBleConnection.setupNotification(uuid0),
        rxBleConnection.setupNotification(uuid1),
        rxBleConnection.setupNotification(uuid2),
        rxBleConnection.setupNotification(uuid3),
        rxBleConnection.setupNotification(uuid4)
        // ...
    )
        .flatMap { it }
```